# Seaborn plot - chronological order

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, seaborn

I have such a Seaborn spaghetti plot from dataframe. As you can see - the dates (in form of string; the first column is the dates of acq; the other - different research sites of measurment) are shuffled and I would like to put them chronologically like in the dataframe. I was looking for some hint on web, but not successful.

[image]

Here's my important part of code:

```
# library and packeges
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import os
from datetime import datetime


# Data test set for year 2015; 8 rapeseed fields.
data = {'Date' : ['3-Mar', '20-Mar', '20-Apr', '21-Apr', '29-Apr', '7-May', '30-May', '31-May', '7-Jun', '16-Jun',
 '1-Jul', '2-Jul', '10-Jul'],
        'Field_1' : [0.5840, 0.8159, 0.7789, 0.7665, 0.8510, 0.7428, 'mraky', 0.6820, 0.8714, 0.8902, 'mraky', 0.8289, 0.6877],
        'Field_2' : [0.6196, 0.8291, 0.7686, 0.7848, 0.9935, 0.7406, 'mraky', 0.6952, 0.6952, 0.6952, 'mraky', 0.8119, 'mraky'],
        'Field_3' : [0.6790, 0.9220, 0.8380, 0.8312, 'mraky', 0.7398, 'mraky', 0.7019, 0.7985, 0.8941, 0.6430, 0.7891, 'mraky'],
        'Field_4' : [0.5570, 0.8285, 0.8084, 0.8340, 0.9095, 'mraky', 'mraky', 0.6675, 0.8648, 0.9536, 0.7933, 0.7641, 0.6566],
        'Field_5' : [0.6085, 0.8404, 0.8036, 0.8009, 'mraky', 0.7811, 0.5960, 0.6685, 0.8815, 'mraky', 'mraky', 0.8438, 0.6959],
        'Field_6' : [0.5187, 0.7611, 0.7920, 0.7935, 0.8554, 0.7151, 0.7929, 0.6657, 0.8697, 0.8842, 0.8055, 0.8304, 0.6531],
        'Field_7' : [0.4110, 0.5756, 0.5911, 0.5538, 0.6688, 0.7373, 0.6962, 0.6345, 0.8210, 0.8376, 0.7750, 0.8033, 0.5736],
        'Field_8' : [0.5225, 0.7648, 0.5691, 0.6819, 0.8134, 'mraky', 0.7281, 0.6799, 0.8590, 0.8786, 'mraky', 0.8475, 0.7056]}


# Data set will be corrected. The string values will changed to None values.
def replace_string_with_None(data, value_to_find, value_for_replacing):
    for key, value in data.items():
        data[key] = [value_for_replacing if i == value_to_find else i for i in value]
    return data
data = replace_string_with_None(data, "mraky", None)
print(data)


# Pandas DataFrame
frame = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(frame)
# Date string altered to Datetime
frame['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(frame['Date'], format='%d-%b', errors='ignore')
frame['Date'] = frame['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d-%b'))
print(frame)

# Seaborn lineplot style and aesthetics.
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(11.7,8.27)})
sns.set_context("talk", rc={"lines.linewidth": 3})


num = 0
for column in frame.drop('Date', axis=1):
        num += 1
        result = sns.lineplot(x = 'Date', y = frame[column], data = frame, marker='o', palette = flatui)
result.set_xlabel('Date of acquisition', fontsize= 20)
result.set_ylabel('NDVI value', fontsize= 20)
result.set_title('Time series of NDVI', fontsize = 22)
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
plt.show()
plt.savefig('myfile.pdf')
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to convert your strings to datetimes, e.g. `pd.to_datetime()`.

Comment: Nope after pd.to_datetime and strftime, result is same or little bit different but still not ordered chronologically.  :-(

Comment: Sure, `strftime` converts back to a string, which is what you should avoid. Note that you may of course provide a [mcve], which would allow someone to actually answer this question.

Comment: Okey. I see, but I need only month and day in my plot. Is it possible?

Comment: You need to distinguish between the position in the plot and the text labels you want to show. Changing the format of the text labels is possible once you have the correct plot.

Comment: Okey! Great now I see. I will try it your way! Btw I've edited the post but I think I've got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Those instances of 'mraky' in your data that you change to None is the cause of the issue. NaN values in data can do strange things to the order the points are treated in plots. Change them to numeric and it should be fine.

Change

```
data = replace_string_with_None(data, "mraky", None)
```

to

```
data = replace_string_with_None(data, "mraky", 0)
```